# Interrogatives Pronomen "welches" korrespondiert nicht mit dem Genus des Nomens?

Tags: pronoun, gender

In der letzten Strophe im Dreigroschenoper-Lied "Moritat von Mackie Messer" (Brecht/Weill) heißt es in der allerletzten Zeile:

> Mackie, **welches** war dein Preis?

Warum nicht **"welcher"**? Dann würde das Pronomen ja zum Nomen (Preis) korrespondieren. Ich habe aber vielleicht etwas falsch verstanden, und das "welches" bezieht sich auf was anderes? Wenn so, könnte es dann mir jemand es erklären?

hier der ganze Text:
https://www.songtexte.com/songtext/bertolt-brecht/die-moritat-von-mackie-messer-23f040cf.html

Comment: Da es in dem ganzen Song um Messer geht, könnte es sich auf Messer beziehen?

Comment: @infinitezero. Kaum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Für mich gibt es einen wichtigen Bedeutungsunterschied, der weder von @fdbs Antwort abgedeckt, noch im verlinkten [Canoonet](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-welcher3.html)-Artikel beschrieben wird.

Meines Erachtens wird mit *welches* nach der *Art des Preises* gefragt. *Welches* wird hier synonym zu *was* verwendet:

> Torsten: „Mackie, *welches*/ *was* war dein Preis?“
>   
>   Mackie: „Ich habe einen Gutschein bekommen.“

*Welcher* würde ich verwenden, um bei mehreren Alternativen einen bestimmten Preis zu erfragen:

> A: „Mackie, *welcher* (Preis) war dein Preis?“
>   
>   B: „Dieser hier gehört Philip, aber der dahinten ist wohl meiner.“

Comment: Ich denke es geht um "Preis/price", nicht um "Preis/prize". https://www.lyrikline.org/de/gedichte/die-moritat-von-mackie-messer

Comment: @fdb, selbst wenn, ändert das nichts an der Verwendung von _welches_ und _welcher_. Nur ist es dann schwieriger (aber sicherlich nicht unmöglich), auf Anhieb ein Beispiel für die Verwendung von _welcher_ zu konstruieren, es sei denn, man interpretiert _Preis_ als Verkürzung, zum Beispiel von _Preisschild_.

Comment: Das ist natürlich nicht falsch, aber m.E. keine Antwort auf die Frage. Der (zutreffende) Kern der Antwort von fdb ist, dass _was/welches_ als genus- und numerusübergreifende Stellvertreter fungieren. Wenn man _was/welches_ nun durch eine maskuline Form des Interrogativums ersetzt, bewirkt das infolge Genusfestlegung zwingend eine Bedeutungsverschiebung hin zu einem maskulinen Korrelat. Im Beispiel kann das nur _Preis_ sein, deswegen liest man dann eine Auswahl aus verschiedenen Preisen hinein. Aber die Frage war ja eigentlich, wie man _welches_ an der Stelle erklärt.

Answer (score 6):

> Wenn die sächliche Form *welches* allein steht und durch das Verb *sein*
>   mit einem Nomen im Nominativ verbunden wird, kann sie sich auf alle
>   Genera und auch auf den Plural beziehen:
>
> Welches ist der richtige Lösungsweg?  auch:   Welcher ist der richtige
>   Lösungsweg?
>
> Welches ist die beste Limonade?   auch:   Welche ist die beste Limonade?
>
> Welches sind die neuen Aufträge und welches die alten?    auch:   Welche
>   sind die neuen Aufträge und welche die alten?

http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-welcher3.html

Eine Erklärung ist das allerdings nicht.

Comment: Gleiches gilt für *das* und *was*: *Das ist der richtige Lösungsweg.*

Comment: @RHa. Ja, genau.

Comment: Danke, dies ist schon eine gute Erklärung. "Welcher" wäre heier also falsch? Wenn du darüber mal ergänzen könntest, bitte.

Comment: @Beta: Ich glaube "welcher" und "welches" sind beide korrekt.